# Error (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error) in oop

Tags: php, pdo

I start to get this error when i add something in database i know what the problem but i tried to solve it but i could not

part of database class:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = FALSE;
    $this->_query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($this->_query) {
        if (count($params)) {
            $x = 1;
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            return $this->_error = TRUE;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
 public function insert($table, $fields = array()){
    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $value = NULL;
    $x = 1;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $value .= '?';
        if ($x < count($fields)) {
            $value .=' , ';
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(`' . implode('`,`', $keys) . '`) VALUES (' . $value . ')';

    if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

this when i insert the data in database

```
try {
            $db->insert('users',  array('username' => $_POST['username'], 
                                        'password' => $pass_hash, 
                                        'Group' => 0));
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
```

everything work fine and code insert the data in database but problem i get this error (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error) because i am trying to fetch the data and i should not fetch it but i want my class be more dynamic , what the way i can fix this ? and thank you

problem form this line

```
$this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: Here is a free advice for you: don't make "database wrappers".

Comment: thank you for advice but what you mean about "database wrappers" i don't get it @tereško

Comment: What you are trying to do is called database wrapper. But hey, pdo is already a database wrapper. So, you are wrapping a wrapper :) Unless you want to write a full ORM, there is little point in doing what you do here. Anyway, you need to detect in the query method whether the query is a select or show that has a resultset before trying to fetch anything.

Comment: i got it now by searching about database wrappers and its really awesome advice and thank you again about it

Comment: i try now to do this put ( throw new Exception() ) instead of (die($ex->getMessage()); ) and its work fine is that correct to do ? @Shadow

Comment: I would rather not call fetch in the first place. It will be difficult to distinguish between a real error and the error you knowingly cause.

Comment: Thank you for this information i will work on it , now make method for fetch if i want it i call the method it should be fine or you have another advice about it ? @Shadow